# Intuitive explanation of concentration of the measure for spheres

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra

What is the concentration of the measure(c.o.m.)?

I am struggling with the following sentence;

***"The phenomenon of the concentration of the measure for spheres in dimensions larger than 2."***

I tried to figure it out about what the c.o.m. is, but I found only mathmetically rigorous explanations that I can't understand.

Please explain what it is. Even better if you have some intuitive examples.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You find a discussion of it in Yuri Manin: *Mathematics and Physics*, Birkhäuser.

Comment: It seems a very interesting book and I do not mind reading it completely, but still - could you please indicate more specifically the place and context in which it is discussed? I believe this would make your answer much more helpful. I found some related explanations at the very beginning, explaining difficulties with the infinite-dimensional integration, is there something more in the text?

Comment: I do not have the book with me now, and it is many years since I read it. But the book is very short so that you can find the relevant part easily.

Comment: @MartinPeters 99 pages, according to https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4899-6782-4 A chapter would be nice to cut it down somewhat.

Comment: Okay, I could check it now: pp 15 to 17.